# Passenger install script reports success but fails to install Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I'm attempting to install Rails + Passenger Phusion + Nginx on my Ubuntu 14.04 headless server.

I have been following this [tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu). All was going well until the section where you hand over to passenger Phusion to install Nginx using the command `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`.

I select the first option that suggests it will install Nginx, and I get a completion message saying Nginx has been successfully installed then I get the following:

```
me@mycomputer:~$ sudo service nginx restart
nginx: unrecognized service
```

I can't understand what's gone wrong here. Could anyone suggest if this is a known issue (perhaps permissions related?) or what commands / logs I might be able to use to set about tracking what's gone wrong?

To be clear the nginx folder exists in `/opt/nginx/` and I have an editable `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `passenger-install-nginx-module` then you cannot use `service nginx restart`. This is because `service nginx` is a script that your Linux distribution provides as part of their Nginx package. passenger-install-nginx-module installs Nginx from source, so you cannot use `service nginx`.

Instead, you will have to restart Nginx by sending it signals, because that's the low-level mechanism that Nginx supports. The `service` script provided by distributions is just a wrapper around sending signals.

See [this wiki page](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Why-can't-Phusion-Passenger-extend-my-existing-Nginx%3F) for more information. It also teaches you how to make an init script that's compatible with the source installation of Nginx.

Comment: You are quite right, humm seems strange the digital ocean page directs you to start it as a service, I guess I shouldn't be comparing their shards to my home server box directly!